# Finding the most recent modification date of all files/subfolders in all top-level directories of a share with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a shared directory tree on a Windows 2003 file server that has about 100GB worth of data in it. I need to find all top-level directories in this share where the last modification time for **every file in every subfolder** hasn't been modified sine 1/1/11. Essentially, I'm looking for shares that are abandoned.

The directory structure looks something like this:

```
-a
--a1
--a2
--a3
----a3_1

-b
--b1
--b2

-c
--c1
----c1_1

etc
```

What I want to do is find out if *everything* that's not a hidden file under a or b or c has a mod date before or after 1/1/11.

So far, I can find the mod times after a year for each file with this:

```
get-childitem "\\server\h$\shared" -recurse | where-object {$_.mode -notmatch "d"} |
where-object {$_.lastwritetime -lt [datetime]::parse("01/01/2011")}
```

What I don't know how to do is check each top level directory individually to see if all of the files contained within it are older than a year. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking to look at only *file* modification times. Not sure what you want to do about folders, which only contain sub-folders that haven't been modified in a year.  I'm also not sure if by *"each top level directory"*, you mean `a`, `b`, `c` or `a`, `a1`, `a2`...

The following looks at *all* directories, and only list them if they do not contain files written within the past year.  Let me know if this produces the output you're looking for:

```
$shareName = "\\server\share"
$directories = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path | Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }

ForEach ( $d in $directories ) { 
    # Any children written in the past year?
    $recentWrites = Get-ChildItem $d.FullName | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $(Get-Date).AddYears(-1) } 
    If ( -not $recentWrites ) {
        $d.FullName
    }
}
```

Edit, per your comment.  If you want get just the top-level directories which do not contain files modified in the past year, try the following.  Note that on very deep/large shares, this may take some time to run.

```
$shareName = "\\server\share"
# Don't -recurse, just grab top-level directories
$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $shareName | Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }
ForEach ( $d in $directories ) { 
    # Get any non-container children written in the past year
    $recentWrites = Get-ChildItem $d.FullName -recurse | Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $(Get-Date).AddYears(-1) } 
    If ( -not $recentWrites ) {
        $d.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: I want each top level directory to be evaluated independently of each other. Basically, I'd like to know if `a` and all files under `a` have been modified within a year. Then I'd like to do the same evaluation for `b` and then `c` and so on. This looks promising though with a little tweaking.

Comment: looking for modification time won't tell you if a file has been abandoned people may just be only reading a file.

Comment: NTFS stores three dates for each file (configurable) - Creation, last modified or changed, and last accessed or read. Looking at Last modified for files in a home directory share tree is the easiest way to identified orphaned shares.  Last read (your example) is better for publicly shared files.

Comment: @tonyroth @RobW I used `LastWriteTime` (last modified) as this is from the OP's question directly.  Last Accessed time can be inaccurate if your back solution does not correctly reset this attribute as it reads the files.

Comment: orphaned shares for home dirs doesn't make sense, thats simple does the user exist or not. and yes @jscott reset archive attributes are a real pain in the butt.

Comment: These aren't home folders. @jscott by top level folders I mean a, b, c. If *everything* under `a` hasn't been modified in over a year, I'd like the output to be a. I don't want each individual subfolder.

Comment: The answer in the edit was the right one for me. Thanks!